# Esquema relacional de 4 tablas

Tags: sql-server

El día de hoy recurro a ustedes para que me puedan dar ayuda sobre el diseño de esta relación de 4 tablas.

Actualmente tengo 4 tablas que tendrá la plataforma. La primera, **proveedores**; la segunda, **editoriales**; la tercera, **libros** y la última, **descuentos**.

La regla de negocio es la siguiente: el administrador podrá crear descuentos a productos por medio de la tabla proveedores, editoriales o específicamente al mismo libro.

Entonces tengo un dilema y puede ser que esté enfocando las relaciones equivocadamente.

Actualmente tengo las siguientes relaciones mer

Proveedor - editorial

- Un Proveedor tiene contrato con varias editoriales y una editorial es contratada por un proveedor.

Editorial - producto

- Una editorial produce varios libros y un libro pertenece a una editorial. *Esto se debe a que el isbn es único para ese libro aunque tengan un mismo nombre*.

A continuación el diagrama

[image: library]

Como tengo esas relaciones, si yo empiezo a relacionar descuentos con proveedores, descuentos con editoriales y descuentos con libros podría tener una relación circular.

El motor de base de datos será MYSQL.

Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda. Dios los bendiga a todos.

La solución que planteo es crear una tabla polimórfica(discountable) para evitar las relaciones circulares y así recibir cualquier tipo de modelo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que es la tabla descuentos? y cual seria el problema con la relacion circular?

Comment: Tienes alguna estructura ya hecha? que has intentado? que motor estas usando? por favor puede especificar en detalle

Comment: @SoftQuick No sé si la imagen que acabo de subir sea específica. Yo veo que el descuento es aplicado a un producto por medio de un proveedor, editorial y producto; esa palabra «por medio» no es un filtro, sino una marca que debe tener en cuenta el sistema a la hora de aplicar un descuento a un producto.

Comment: @SoftQuick Podría crear una tabla polimórfica para establecer una relación con los modelos dados por la publicación. Con eso podría crear descuentos por cualquier modelo dado, pero el sistema no sabría cuál descuento aplicar. Entonces tendría que crear una regla de negocio jerárquica y establecer quién tiene prioridad para aplicar un descuento.

Comment: exactamente, intenta hacerlo pues sino entonces abrimos un debate

Comment: @SoftQuick No sé si se cierra la publicación o se deja por si existe alguna respuesta más. Soy nuevo en estas comunidades. Gracias por todo.

Comment: La puedes dejar asi, en caso de que requieras algo pues nuevamente lo comentas y abrimos el debate

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una tabla `"DescuentoPorTipo"`, la cual tendria una `PK` compuesta por cuatro campos, el primero el `Tipo de Descuento`, el segundo que puede ser el `ID` de Proveedor, Editorial o Producto, el tercero un `Indice`, y el cuarto el `ID` del descuento. Por ejemplo, digamos que el tipo de descuento a Proveedores se indique con `01`, el `ID` del Proveedor es `12` y es el `8vo` descuento que se le aplica,  ademas se aplico el descuento con `ID 6`, el registro en la tabla quedaria algo como:

> 01 | 12  |  8  | 6

Ademas de esta forma es muy facil controlar el acceso concurrente.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre crear este tipo de tablas y una tabla polimórfica?

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.